# how to open files in succession without manually giving file_name input .(usage of for loop)

Tags: c++, file

Command to open files with file names as follows f_0,f_1,f_2,f_3,.....and so on.I want to use a for loop in c++ to open these files in successive iterative steps .I have a lot of other code running in between the iterative steps.I dont want to give manual input of file name at each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to generate these filenames. Here's one example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_FILES; i++ ) {
    std::stringstream s;
    s << "f_" << i;
    std::string filename = s.str();

    // open the file

    ...
}
```

This is even simpler but requires C++11 or later:

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_FILES; i++ ) {
    std::string filename = "f_" + std::to_string(i);

    // open the file

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Determine file name for each step inside the loop:

```
bool openNextFile = true;
int fileIndex = 0;
int maxFileIndex = 100
FILE * pFile;
while(openNextFile )
{
    pFile = fopen("f_" + To<std::string>(fileIndex), "w");
    //do stuff
    fclose(pFile);
    fileIndex++;
    if (fileIndex == maxFileIndex - 1)
    {
        openNextFile = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `To<std::string>(fileIndex)`?